# PHP RegEx for removing a Blockquote

Tags: php, regex

I'm using a preg replace to remove a twitter embeded tweet from a string something that looks like this

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>Frank Lampard challenges for the ball... <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23CFC&amp;src=hash">#CFC</a> <a href="http://t.co/CALSJZx2Fu">pic.twitter.com/CALSJZx2Fu</a></p>&mdash; Chelsea FC (@chelseafc) <a href="https://twitter.com/chelseafc/statuses/384596498110877696">September 30, 2013</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Its coming up with an error

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'b' in /inc/functions_custom.php on line 261
```

Here is my PHP regex - not sure whats wrong.

```
$string = preg_replace('/([\s\S]*)(<blockquote>)([\s\S]*)(</blockquote>)([\s\S]*)/', "", $string);
```

Comment: use `<\/blockquote>` instead of `</blockquote>`

Comment: did you try my answer? cos I tried it n it worked

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
/(<blockquote)(.*)(<\/blockquote>)/
```

You have closed your `blockquote` tag in your regex. Whereas in your search string, your `blockquote` tag has attributes

`(<blockquote>)` has to be `(<blockquote)`

and

`(</blockquote>)` has to be `(<\/blockquote>)`